# Firebug for PHP

Tags: php, ide, firebug

Firebug is such a spectacular development tool for javascript, is there any kind of strong analog for PHP? I have seen this PHP (and Drupal) extension for Firebug, but it seems like they are no longer maintained. Specifically in terms of console, net, and yslow functionality?

Comment: If you ever see some browser extension that is supposed to help you debug your PHP, stay far far away.  PHP is server-side, and should be debugged server-side.  John has mentioned the defacto method below.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, just because they're buggy then?

Comment: No, because they are fundamentally flawed.  The client (browser) doesn't know and doesn't care that you're running PHP on the back-end.  All of those tools that try to help you debug PHP in the browser work by adding crap to your PHP output, which can really mess things up while you try to debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and [Wincachegrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) are great debuggers and profilers for PHP

Answer (score 2):

You also can try FirePHP: http://www.firephp.org/

Comment: Is this active? I think I tried to get this working on ff and failed?